# How to instantiate/use Transform interface Commons Math?

Tags: java, transformation, affinetransform, apache-commons-math

Is it possible to use [`Transform`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/partitioning/Transform.html) interface from Apache Commons Math to actually transform numerical vectors? If "yes" then how? No clues in Apidoc. If "no" then what is the purpose of this interface?

**UPDATE**

Interface above is hyperlinked. I mean `org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.partitioning.Transform<S extends Space,T extends Space>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the RealTransformer interface in the org.apache.commons.math3.transform package, you need to either use directly one of the concrete implementations in that package or create one of your own.  Have a look at, e.g FastFourierTransformer for an example implementation. You are welcome to ask for help on the commons user mailing list.